# return first view not-numeric chars of string in SQL function fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to return the prefix of a VAT number with a SQL function. Because of some changes in these numbers and differences in countries and mistakes in the database, the length of the prefix differs from 0 to 4 characters. So the input of my function is a string, with a prefix of not numeric characters and then some numbers. For example ES012345678, and then i only want to return ES.

I wrote a function for it and it fails, it only returns NULL, even when the input is like the example.

Anyone knows where my mistake is?

here is my SQL code:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[returnPreOfVat] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @VATstring varchar
)
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result varchar
     DECLARE @char varchar(2)
     DECLARE @counter int
     SET @counter =1;
     SET @char = '';

    WHILE (@counter < 5) --check some from the front
        BEGIN
        SET @char = SUBSTRING(@VATstring, @counter,1); --get next char from front
        IF(ISNUMERIC(@char)<>1) -- not numeric
            BEGIN
            SET @Result = @Result + @char;
            END
        SET @counter=@counter+1;
        END
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
```

Comment: You don't declare the size of Result and you don't initialize Result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never initialize the result , Please try:

```
DECLARE @Result varchar = ''
```

If recall correctly NULL + str = NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I think a loop is overkill here. I'd combine the LEFT and PATINDEX functions

```
select LEFT(@VATstring, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @VATstring)-1)
```